# Get Sum of score of a team which is present in multiple rows and two columns MySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I want to get the total score of a team which can be in multiple rows and 2 columns (1: FirstTeamName, 2: SecondTeamName) at max for any given EventName. 
It will be a PHP function given only eventName as parameter

[image: Please see the attached image of table]

E.g: In this case total score of Team 2 is = 1+4+3 = 8

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate:

```
select eventname, team, sum(score)
from ((select eventname, firstteamname as team, firstteamscore as score
       from t
      ) union all
      (select eventname, secondteamname as team, secondteamscore as score
       from t
      ) 
     ) t
group by eventname, team;
```

If you want to filter on a particular event, I would recommend doing that in the two subqueries.

Comment: Mr Gordon, 
this query works perfect! I had to do a very lengthy and costly job with php to achieve this result, now i'll replace it.
Thank you very much!